# Equation for a curve initially concave, then convex, and then concave again

Tags: curves, parametrization

First time poster! Sorry if I have missed a similar answer (I did search and didn't find a suitable answer.)

For an economic application where I am defining utility $u(w)$ over wealth, $w$, I want the curve to be concave up to some wealth $w_1$, then convex till wealth $w_2$, and then concave again till $\infty$. If it makes things easier it is fine to restrict the domain to just $0\le w\le 1$, so $w_1$ and $w_2$ would be fractions. (I can just change the units of wealth!)

[Depiction of the desired curve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksGMS.jpg)

Comment: You need to give more details: what work have you done, any further context?, etc.  This is not a do-my-homework-for-me site.  And don't search for a suitable answer when you don't have a suitable question.

Comment: if polynomial has $n$ turning points then it's degree is $n-1$.

Comment: information is insufficient.Attach photo of question "as it is" given in the book

Comment: Hint: find a function $f(w)$ that is positive up to $w_1$, then negative up to $w_2$, and then positive thereafter, and then integrate $f$ twice.

Comment: Thanks the idea but did you mean of n+1 degree polynomial? I guess getting there by integrating a suitable n-1 degree polynomial twice seems promising.